# Passing a converter to a composite component

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2, composite-component

After some experimenting and reading up, I found the same solution as [How to reference component inside a composite component when using a converter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38919946/how-to-reference-component-inside-a-composite-component-when-using-a-converter)

The problem however is that I have two IDs for the valueholder and according to the documentation I could use id1,id2 as targets but that doesn't work.

This is my composite component:

```
<cc:interface>
    <cc:attribute name="id" required="true"/>
    <cc:attribute name="value" required="true"/>
    <cc:attribute name="editable" required="true"/>
    <cc:editableValueHolder name="element" targets="input,output"/>
</cc:interface>
<cc:implementation>
    <h:inputText value="#{cc.attrs.value}" id="input" rendered="#{cc.attrs.editable}"/>
    <h:outputText value="#{cc.attrs.value}" id="output" rendered="#{not cc.attrs.editable}"/>
</cc:implementation>
```

And this is how I intend to use the CC:

```
<r:inputText editable="#{registrationBean.editable}" id="dateOfBirth"
             value="#{registrationBean.dateOfBirth}">
    <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd-MM-yyyy" type="date" for="element" />
</r:inputText>
```

I originally tried inserting the converter via insertChildren and via a facet but none worked.

Answer (score 0):

`target` needs to be space separated not comma separated

> If present, this must be a space (not tab) separated list of client
>   ids (relative to the top level component) of components within the
>    section. Space is used as the delimiter for
>   compatibility with the IDREFS and NMTOKENS data types from the XML
>   Schema.

[JSF2.2 docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserver-faces-2-2/vdldocs-facelets/cc/editableValueHolder.html)

Comment: I have tried a space as well. In fact I changed the snippet here to use a comma because the original snippet has it with space.

Comment: Could it have to do with commented lines of code in my composite component/call site? I removed some commented code and suddenly it appears to be working. I don't yet feel safe about it but oh well...

Answer (score -1):

I came through the same problem, but I also a beginner with composite's.

I defined my composite, but the `<f:convertDateTime>` was not used inside the composite.
So I moved the `<f:convertDateTime>` inside, but also not working!

Like:

```
    <p:inputText id="#{cc.attrs.id}" readonly="#{cc.attrs.readonly}" rendered="#{cc.attrs.rendered}"
        value="#{cc.attrs.value}">
        <f:convertDateTime pattern="#{DateAdapter.DATEPATTERN_LOCAL}" />
    </p:inputText>
```

Access to `DateAdapter.DATEPATTERN_LOCAL` was NOT the problem.

First after changing the input parameter from typeless to Date type:

```
    <cc:attribute name="value" required="true" type="java.util.Date" />
```

the `<f:convertDateTime>` was used at all.

But I still can not pass from caller to the composite using `<cc:insertChildren />`

Comment: Sorry, this is not a correct answer. You just forgot specifying the `for` attribute as seen in the code example in the question as well as in the link in top in the question. OP's actual problem had a different cause.